# Anatomically Correct Mi-Go

Tags: science-based, magic, creature-design, anatomically-correct

This is part of [the Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series) and has observed all updated rules for that series.

Since I have already [created a Hell](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/225831/can-a-brain-in-a-jar-be-killed-or-have-a-reduced-lifespan-from-psychological-tra) designed by creatures who are inspired by the Lovecraftian Mi-Go race, I now need to try to come up with an anatomically correct alien species that fits the description, in more modern terms. **Note: These creatures occupy the world I designed. In no possible way could an explanation for my creature derive from the C'thulu mythos or any Lovecraftian worlds. Reference to commercial products are only for descriptive purposes, and no commercial third-party product is being amended or used in any possible way.**

- magic: I personally have never once used magic in my writing, and don't like to do so. Realistically, this alien shares the characteristics of a god-like creature in a world chock full of gods and things which blatantly defy physics. Lovecraft, a fervid student of physics, *employed* his understanding of natural law to effect his horror by finding holes and shaking our faith in them. So I accept that I may not be able to escape using *some* supernatural forces for this creature. My goal is to make it as minimal as possible: thus, if a physical answer *can* explain it, then a magical one shall not. The science-based tag trumps the magic tag everywhere possible. Also, the "magic," if needed, won't be intelligent or "god-derived;" it will be a simple alteration of some force or physical property—preferably quantum probabilities of light/particles/matter becoming non-Gausian—inexplicably connected with their corporeal form.

### Single cause answer

My goal in an answer is to have a single feature of this creature be the cause of the three listed side effects. E.g., should we want a world that has all features of liquid water, precipitation, and navigable waterways, this could be built from three separate questions with a potpourri of incompatible solutions, or we could simply say the world is in the "goldilocks zone" and the world has better believability.

**Research:** The description of the Mi-Go varies from different reports. My world has no preference in this physical appearance as it may not even be the creature’s true form (see side effect 2). The only commonly accepted fact about my creature is that they are essentially fungi in their biology. A couple drawn pictures are included below from different reports.

[image: Mi-Go from The Fungi of Yuggoth]

And another artist rendition of a Mi-Go with a brain in a vat:

[image: Mi-Go Rendering]

### 1. Physical side effect: Locomotion through the environment

The Mi-Go-like creatures  originate in space, using energy in an extremely exotic way, that contributes to the three side-effects. **Research:** On earth, we have discovered bacteria deep in the crust which actually feeds on radioactive decay. I considered that a highly radioactive protoplanet or other body could serve as a likely birthplace for these creatures in an answer. They can also survive in and travel through "the aether" (space) by some method of locomotion. For this, my research suggests there may be either some sort of reaction engine such as ion propulsion, or if this is infeasible, a supernatural manipulation of forces will need to explain this. (Note that the Mi-Go did walk around and leave "claw tracks,"
but my creatures do not require this. So they do not need to be ambulatory or very massive since that will complicate flight and space travel.)

### 2. Optical illusion side effect: Inability to record

The Mi-Go can not be recorded on camera film or other capture media. Neither can mine due to this characteristic of the world.  It does not ever say that they are "invisible" on these media, but neither their form nor image will reproduce accurately on a film or other media. Like the Mi-Go, they can apparently be described by a human observer, however, so unless a more scientifically compatible answer exists, I accept that human cones and rods can detect and signal light emissions from them. **Research:** The visions which reach a human mind are not simple reproductions of what reaches our eyes. [A rare and horrifying disorder causes you to see the right half of human faces as if they are melting](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2252625-man-sees-half-of-every-face-like-its-melting-due-to-rare-brain-lesion/#:%7E:text=chemistry-,Man%20sees%20half%20of%20every%20face%20like,due%20to%20rare%20brain%20lesion&text=A%20man%20with%20a%20rare,one%20half%20of%20the%20face.), which leads scientists to conclude that our brains are doing a significant amount of image processing before we recognize what we see. In an answer, "hallucinogenic" is a scientifically sound explanation for the ability for a human to describe this creature: Our description of them does not in fact come from what reaches our eyes, but instead, they actively or passively "cause" the form of their appearance in our minds. The world can sidestep a complicated explanation with light working differently on film and on a retina. The lore on Mi-Go tells that they are composed of an unnatural form of matter which prevents light from rendering an accurate image of them. My world rejects exotic forms of matter which are not scientifically sound within our more modern concepts. In an answer, this optical obscurity, whether it be hallucinogenic or otherwise, is again preferred to share the same cause as the creature's ability to fly and traverse space; "magic" being a last resort fall-back.

The Mi-Go appear to fly in fluids by means of wings, which flap slowly. In an answer, I can accept that this may also be part of their hallucination effect if actual "wings" don't contribute to the answer.

## 3. Psychosocial side effect: Brains

They have a need or use for human servants as brains in a vat. They need our intelligence for some purpose, but our bodies are incompatible (or unnecessary) for that purpose. So they only take our brains and keep them alive. Whatever odd  feature of the world that causes the other traits in this question should also directly relate to this need for live human intellect. Obviously not as a "physical" need, but because that feature of this world which causes their mobility and optical obscurity has left them needing human intellect, or perhaps some portion of our processing ability to interface with "the real world." **Research:** Mi-Go are extremely intelligent but have vastly incompatible moral values to us, which my creatures share. So the need for our intellect may relate to that.
**Clarification:** The jar is explained simply because transporting the mass of a whole human body is too cumbersome. They don't need a human, they need human intellect. So they discard the 98% of a human that they do not need.

Comment: Are you asking a question? Remember that questions on this site need to be specific, not open ended discussion prompts. I searched your whole post and I don't see a single question mark.

Comment: VTC: [We do not answer questions about 3rd party or commercial worlds](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7336/40609). This is [specifically stated in the ACS rules](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2797/40609). The works of H.P. Lovecraft [may or may not be in the public domain](https://lovecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Copyright_status_of_works_by_H._P._Lovecraft), but that doesn't mean they're not commercial. They are.

Comment: seem like op want a science-based answer to justify those 3 topics for this creature
-able to space travel on it own
-camera can't/barely able to capture their form
-want human's brain

Comment: @YowaneHaku If that was the case then OP could make a quick edit to their question and it would still not be a good fit for this site given our no questions about existing works of fiction policy and our one question per post policy. We also require that questions be sufficiently specific to not have many valid answers. If we're charitable and allow for posts not asking a single question on a question and answer site, this is still far more of a request for brainstorming and idea generation than this site permits.

Comment: @JBH I am not in any way building on any existing world. Lovecraft’s worlds are filled with gods. He directly defies science in his horror.

Comment: @sphennings The problem statement is in the first paragraph, second sentence: “ I now need to try to come up with an anatomically correct alien species that fits the description, in more modern terms.” You can quickly re-arrange this into a question by changing “I need to...” into “How can I …”

Comment: @VogonPoet The King Kong Q probably asked before the 3rd party rule was formalized under current rules that Q would not be permitted as written. If you want to ask about your Mi-Go knockoffs, that would be permitted but you are required to "file off all the labels" and describe the creatures in the body of the question, without relying on 3rd party canon. Then you need to ask a single specific question, one that isn't brainstorming or fishing for ideas.

Comment: Going from saying *"I need to try to come up with an anatomically correct alien species that fits the description, in more modern terms."* to asking *"How can I  try to come up with an anatomically correct alien species that fits the description, in more modern terms."* will still leave you with a question that isn't a good fit. There are many different methods of coming up with aliens each are equally valid. If you asked how to make an "anatomically correct alien" you'd then need to explain what you mean by AC in the context of a Mi-Go. Otherwise you're just fishing for ideas, which isn't ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137925/discussion-between-vogon-poet-and-sphennings).

Comment: (a) Today's rules, including the existing ACS rules, are the only rules that count. No previous Q *on any Stack* may ever serve as precedent to break current rules.  That's explained in the ACS rules (bullet #6). (b) The fact that you've placed somebody else's creature in your own world doesn't change the fact that you're asking about Lovecraft's creature. From the ACS rules: "the ACS is now limited to questions about *documented myths and legends of Humanity* and *creatures **thoroughly designed** (other than lacking anatomical fulfillment) for a fictional world of the OP's own creation.*"

Comment: It's hard to tell the difference between studying an existing world and making a copy-pasta for a new world. Telling you're creating your own world isn't really a proof you're doing the latter, we already expect that ^^'. But anyway, first ask about why does a creature want brains, then why can't they be caught on cameras then how can they live on Pluto; Each individual questions have a clearer worldbuilding purpose, as you can mix/match answers more freely than "copying this work for your own". Plus... It's much more focused ^^.

Comment: @JBH I have addressed the charge of [Lovecraftian intrusion on the meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9833/canonical-delphicity-is-the-line-we-must-observe-in-judging-third-party-worlds), with what I hope can paint a hard line for us to observe.

Answer (score 1):

Highly evolved parasitic fungi

Creature originated from somewhere in space which they already dominated their home planet, taking over most/all of living organism on it and now in search of new hunting ground.
their mixed appearance is multiple of prey merged together being as puppet/host for fungi colony to goes anywhere (airborne amphibian)- common things they shared is having wing and some kind of aquatic feature fitting your description.

The ability to space travel is borderline plausible but still, by stockpile enough resource to create a enclosed self-sustained environment in it host body, then cover itself with an air-tight layer(s), fly out to the space and floating till it find new planet.

In detail info to check out is it air-tight layer(s) which should have mycorrhizal networks within it, developed into fiber-optic-like providing light for the enclosed environment inside the main body / vacuum(or almost vacuum) in-between layer to prevent heat lost, said layer should be able to survive entering planet's atmosphere to certain extend etc [or when in doubt, you throw in magic as an excuse]

For inability to be recorded, from mentioned fiber optic mycorrhizal networks, they can manipulate it to camouflaged itself - simple enough, redirecting light hitting itself to observer and they will only see the light, redirecting all light output away from observer and they will see/appear in photo as dark spot.

Lastly, what about the brain?, they interesting in our brain because the complexity/ potential that they could use it to evolve itself further (either it be more suitable host or whatever reason) and they want only the brain because the rest is useless to them (no need for respiratory, vascular system etc)

Irl there is a parasitic fungi that can control ant and make it move to higher place over it own nest to spread the spore to others in it host colony and if possible, go read more about mycorrhizal networks.